# Converting a python script to be run on a GPU (CUDA)

Tags: python, numpy, cuda, gpu, numba

I'm trying to get the following code to run on my RTX 3080 instead of my CPU:

```
import decimal
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool


def can_root(x):
    for i in range(2, (x // 2) + 1):
        y = float(round(decimal.Decimal(x ** (1 / i)), 20))
        if y.is_integer():
            y = int(y)
            a = [i]
            while True:
                go_again = 0
                for p in range(2, (y // 2) + 1):
                    go_again = 0
                    z = round(decimal.Decimal(y ** (1 / p)), 4)
                    z = float(z)
                    if z.is_integer():
                        z = int(z)
                        y = z
                        a.append(p)
                        go_again = 1
                        break
                if go_again == 1:
                    continue
                break
            y = int(y)
            power = 1
            for value in a:
                power *= value
            return x, y, power
    return None


def main():
    data = []
    pool = Pool(32)
    for result in pool.map(can_root, range(100000000, 999999999)):
        if result is not None:
            data.append(result)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    np.savez_compressed('data.npz', dta=data, allow_pickle=False)  # for portability

    loadback = np.load('data.npz')['dta']
    print(loadback)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Even with 32 threads to run this, it would take years (I haven't done the math so don't quote me on that but it's a while). I'm hoping that it would run much faster on a GPU than a CPU based on the repetitive nature of the script. However, I've been having some trouble with converting it. I haven't had any experience with CUDA at all nor converting Python to CUDA so I'm walking in blind. I have tried enlisting the help of Chatgpt and Bard however the memes are right, 5 minutes of coding and 5 years of debugging. So far I've tried using this [Py2CUDA](https://github.com/Yuvix25/Py2CUDA) however I can't find any documentation and it keeps throwing a lot of errors with my code, and [NUMBA](https://numba.pydata.org/) However I haven't been able to integrate it that well with my code but if someone can tell if it can and I just missed something great! There are 3 things I'm really looking for and I hope someone can help.

1. Will it actually perform better on a GPU?
2. Can I just add some decorators to my code and with a good enough library *poof* it works on a GPU, or will I basically have to rewrite every line of the script
3. I haven't had much luck finding a good tutorial or guide regarding Python to CUDA so if anyone knows a good one that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain what the function `can_root` does? Besides, I feel that GPU usually speeds up array or matrix calculations, and it might be not helpful in your case.

Comment: The decimal package is not supported on the GPU. Whatever it is you are trying to achieve, you will have to do it with standard binary IEEE single or double precision floating point arithmetic

Comment: Apparently `can_root` finds the least `y` such that `y^p == x` and `y`, `p` are positive integers. Decimal is used only for conversion float->Decimal->float which is kinda pointless.

Comment: @SpaceFlier, I suppose this problem is either a fun project or a problem from some online resource and you're interested in solving it efficiently yourself. You don't need CUDA to solve it quickly, it would benefit more from an algorithmic optimization. Think about your `can_root` and how it can be reimplemented much more efficiently. The most optimal solution I can think of doesn't have `can_root` at all and should run in Python in less than a second (single-threaded) for the given range.

Comment: As is, your solution requires about 10^18 operations, so, although it can be implemented to utilize GPU almost perfectly (10^9 independent tasks with almost zero memory usage), you'll still have to wait a few years for the result.

Comment: @talonmies `double` is too slow on gaming cards. So I've posted a work-around for this specific question.

Comment: @maxplus you're right. The correct solution is to see that OP asked the wrong question, and remove `can_root` completely

Answer (score 4):

Here's 1 solution in CUDA using @jared algorithm, 1 solution using a better algorithm, and the best solution. I implemented **4 versions** total to show better algorithm > better hardware (you asked for the 2nd).

Time cost to find `res = [can_root(n) for n in range(0, 10^9]` are:

- Your original code: ~7000 years
- @jared answer: ~40 days
- @jared algo using C++ (`can_root_cpu`): ~3.3 days
- @jared algo using CUDA (`can_root`): **50 seconds on 2080ti, probably much faster on 3080**
- Better algorithm (`can_root_cpu_sieve`): **18 seconds for creating Sieve of Eratosthenes, 19 seconds for can_root -> 37s total**
- Best algorithm (don't use `can_root`): **0.1 second**. The code used for testing is actually really slow and takes 2 seconds because it requires writing to an array size `B`, instead of just collecting the required values.

The algorithm by @jared has cost `O(N * sqrt(N))`. With `N = 10^5`, his Python code takes `3.47 second`. So with `N = 10^9`, it'll take `3.47 second * (10^9 / 10^5) * sqrt(10^9 / 10^5) = 40 days`. Your code has time complexity `O(N^2)`.

Sieve algo has time complexity around `O(N * log(log(N))`, and the best solution has cost `O(sqrt(B - A) * log(log(sqrt(B - A))`. I'll give you a solution with cost `O(sqrt(B) * log(log(sqrt(B)))`, since the ideas are similar.

For @jared algorithm on GPU, we need a few tricks:

- `double == fp64` is EXTREMELY slow on gaming cards. On 2080ti, FP32 performance is  13.45 TFLOP; while FP64 performance is 0.42 TFLOP -> 1:32 ratio
- So, we have to use `float`. But it has low precision, and we'll get a lot of wrong answers (I've tested) with this algorithm.
- So instead of just checking `if abs(b - round(b)) < tol:`, we also check `candiate^b == n` **using integers**. Then it'll be correct. Most of the time `abs(b - round(b)) >= tol`, so this extra check doesn't add noticeable cost.
- If `n = a^b` is an even number, `a` must be an even number. Similar when `n` is odd. So, we only need to loop over either even or odd numbers. This save 50% of the time cost.

---

My improved `can_root_cpu_sieve` uses the following ideas:

- `N` can be factored into array of prime numbers length K with the form: `N = np.prod([prime[k] ^ expo[k] for k in range(K)]`. For example, `18 = 3^2 * 2^1`, `36 = 3^2 * 2^2`.
- If `a^b = N`, then `expo[k] % b == 0 for k in range(K)`. Also we only accept `b > 1`
- `a` will be smallest when `b` is largest -> `b = gcd(expo[:])`, and `a = np.prod([prime[k] ^ (expo[k] / b) for k in range(K)]`
- To quickly find prime factors of a number, we need to initialize a Sieve of Eratosthenes. In my code, `sieve[N] = largest prime factor of N`. To factor, do something like `while (sieve[N] != 1) N /= sieve[N];`

---

The best solution is also the simplest. `a^b = N`, `b >= 2`, `N <= 10^9` means `a <= sqrt(10^9)`.

We can just loop over all possible `a` and `b` and compute `a^b`.

```
for (int a = sqrt(B) + 1; a >= 2; a--) {
    int64_t n = a;
    for (int b = 2; b <= 30; b++) {
      n *= a;
      if (n >= B) break;
      ...
}
```

The inner loop cost around `log(log(sqrt(B)))` on average, so the total time cost is `sqrt(B) * log(log(sqrt(B)))`

---

The program below computes `res = [can_root(n) for n in range(A, B]` using both CPU and GPU, and compares their results to make sure it's correct. It also measures run time. You can replace `can_root_cpu_sieve` with `can_root_cpu` to confirm that all 4 versions give the same results.

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using std::cout;

class MyTimer {
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start;

public:
    void startCounter() {
        start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    }

    int64_t getCounterNs() {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start).count();
    }

    int64_t getCounterMs() {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start).count();
    }

    double getCounterMsPrecise() {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start).count()
                / 1000000.0;
    }
};

__host__ __device__
int intpow(int x, int n) {
  int res = 1;
  int mult = x;
  while (n) {
    if (n & 1) res *= mult;
    mult = mult * mult;
    n >>= 1;
  }
  return res;
}

void can_root_cpu(int *res, const int A, const int B, float eps_big = 1e-7, float eps_small = 1e-10)
{
  for (int n = A; n < B; n++) {
    int idx = 2 * (n - A);
    res[idx] = 0;
    res[idx + 1] = 0;

    int lim = round(sqrt(n));
    for (int candidate = 2; candidate <= lim; candidate++) {
      double b = log(n) / log(candidate);
      double diff = fabs(b - round(b));
      if (diff < eps_small) {
        res[idx + 1] = round(b);
        res[idx] = candidate;
        break;
      } else if (diff < eps_big) {
        // in case the difference is small but not tiny, we check using int.
        // This is because float might have precision issue
        int bint = round(b);
        if (intpow(candidate, bint) == n) {
          res[idx + 1] = bint;
          res[idx] = candidate;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

int gcd(int a, int b) {
  while (b) {
    int temp = b;
    b = a % b;
    a = temp;
  }
  return a;  
}

void can_root_cpu_sieve(int* __restrict__ res, const int A, const int B,
                        const int* __restrict__  sieve,
                        float eps = 1e-10)
{
  std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> factors;
  factors.reserve(64);

  for (int n = A; n < B; n++) {
    int idx = 2 * (n - A);
    res[idx] = 0;
    res[idx + 1] = 0;

    factors.clear();    
    int N = n;
    int prime_factor_gcd = 0;

    while (N != 1) {
      const int K = sieve[N];
      int expo = 0;
      if (K > 1) {
        while (N % K == 0) {
          N /= K;
          expo++;
        }
      } else {
        prime_factor_gcd = 1;
        break;
      }      

      if (prime_factor_gcd == 0) prime_factor_gcd = expo;
      else prime_factor_gcd = gcd(prime_factor_gcd, expo);
      if (prime_factor_gcd == 1) break;

      factors.emplace_back(K, expo);
    }

    if (prime_factor_gcd <= 1) continue;

    int base = 1;
    for (const auto &data : factors)
      base *= intpow(data.first, data.second / prime_factor_gcd);
    res[idx] = base;
    res[idx + 1] = prime_factor_gcd;        
  }
}

void gen_can_root(int* __restrict__ res, const int A, const int B) {  
  int lim = round(sqrt(B)) + 1;

  for (int a = lim; a >= 2; a--) {
    int64_t n = a;
    for (int b = 2; b <= 30; b++) {
      n *= a;
      if (n >= B) break;

      res[2 * (n - A)] = a;
      res[2 * (n - A) + 1] = b;
    }
  }
}

//--------------------

__global__
void can_root(int *res, const int A, const int B, float eps = 1e-4)
{
  const int start = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  const int stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;

  for (int n = A + start; n < B; n += stride) {
    int idx = 2 * (n - A);
    res[idx] = 0;
    res[idx + 1] = 0;

    int lim = roundf(sqrtf(n));
    const int start_candidate = (n % 2 == 0) ? 2 : 3;
    
    for (int candidate = start_candidate; candidate <= lim; candidate += 2) {
      float b = logf(n) / logf(candidate);
      if (fabsf(b - roundf(b)) < eps) {
        int bint = lroundf(b);
        if (intpow(candidate, bint) == n) {
          res[idx + 1] = bint;
          res[idx] = candidate;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int A = 2;
  int B = 1'000'000;
  bool test_sieve = 0;
  
  if (argc == 2) {
    B = std::stoi(argv[1]);
  }
  if (argc >= 3) {
    A = std::stoi(argv[1]);
    B = std::stoi(argv[2]);    
  }
  if (argc >= 4) {
    test_sieve = 1;
  }

  //--------------
  MyTimer timer;
  int* res0;
  int* res1;

  timer.startCounter();  
  cudaMallocManaged(&res0, (B - A) * 2 * sizeof(int));
  res1 = new int[(B - A) * 2 * sizeof(int)];  
  cudaMemsetAsync(res0, 0, (B - A) * 2 * sizeof(int), 0);
  memset(res1, 0, (B - A) * 2 * sizeof(int));
  cout << "Allocate memory = " << timer.getCounterMsPrecise() << "\n";

  int* sieve;
  int sieve_size = B;
  if (test_sieve) {
    timer.startCounter();
    sieve = new int[sieve_size];
    for (int i = 0; i < sieve_size; i++) sieve[i] = 1;
    sieve[0] = 0;
    sieve[1] = 1;
    
    for (int i = 2; i < sieve_size; i++) {
      if (sieve[i] > 1) continue;
      // Normally it's "j = i * i" because it's faster.
      // But "j = 2 * i" will give sorted prime factors
      for (int j = 2 * i; j < sieve_size; j += i) {
        sieve[j] = i;
      }
    }
    cout << "sieve cost = " << timer.getCounterMsPrecise() << "\n";
  }

  int ntest = 5;
  int wrong = 0;
  double total_cost[2] = {0};
  for (int t = 0; t <= ntest; t++) {
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    timer.startCounter();
    can_root<<<1024,512>>>(res0, A, B);    
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    double cost0 = timer.getCounterMsPrecise();
    total_cost[0] += cost0;

    timer.startCounter();
    //can_root_cpu(res1, A, B);
    if (test_sieve) can_root_cpu_sieve(res1, A, B, sieve);
    else gen_can_root(res1, A, B);
    double cost1 = timer.getCounterMsPrecise();
    total_cost[1] += cost1;

    cout << "cost = " << cost0 << " " << cost1 << "\n";

    for (int n = A; n < B; n++) {
      int idx = 2 * (n - A);
      if (res0[idx] != res1[idx] || res0[idx + 1] != res1[idx + 1]) {
        cout << "ERROR " << n << " " << res0[idx] << " " << res0[idx + 1] << " " << res1[idx] << " " << res1[idx + 1] << std::endl;
        wrong++;
        if (wrong >= 10) exit(1);
      }
    }
    cudaMemPrefetchAsync(res0, (B - A) * 2 * sizeof(int), 0, 0);
  }

  if (wrong == 0) {
    cout << "NO ERROR" << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Use the script `./run.sh A B test_sieve`

```
nvcc -o main can_root.cu -O3 -std=c++17
./main $1 $2 $3
```

such as

```
./run.sh 0 1000000 0 # compare GPU vs optimal solution, B = 10^6
./run.sh 2 1000000 1 # compare GPU vs sieve solution, A = 2, B = 10^6
./run.sh 0 1000000000 0 # GPU vs optimal, B = 10^9
```

**Note:** So we have reduced the time cost from 7000 years to ~37 seconds, just by changing the algorithm (and language). And reduced it to ~0.1 second, by rephrasing the problem. Using GPU isn't enough to make up for the difference in big-O time cost.

It's possible to optimize this further, but I'll leave that as an exercise.

Comment: Nice. Complexity of the best solution you posted is actually even better, `O(sqrt(N))`. There's also another approach to optimize `can_root` without a large memory usage but with a slightly worse complexity: check roots of degrees and logarithms to bases below k such that `k^k > B`.

Answer (score 2):

Jumping straight from what you have to using a GPU to speed up your code is a mistake. The first step is to actually optimize the algorithm. Your algorithm is overly complicated, which makes it slow (see the numbers below).

Your problem is to find *a* and *b* where *a^b = n*. The smallest *a* can be is 2 and the largest is *sqrt(n)* (since *b* cannot be smaller than 2). You can then make use of logarithms to rewrite the problem as looking for what base logarithm (i.e. *a*) of *n* returns an integer result. Looping through all the possible values of *a*, you check if the result is an integer (because of floating point arithmetic, I wrote the check to be based on some set tolerance).

```py
import math

def can_root(n, tol=1e-10):
    for candidate in range(2, math.floor(math.sqrt(n))+1):
        b = math.log(n, candidate)
        if abs(b - round(b)) < tol:
            b = int(round(b))
            a = int(round(n**(1/b)))
            return n, a, b
    return None

results = []
for n in range(2, 100000):
    result = can_root(n)
    if result is not None:
        results.append(result)
```

This is an inherently computationally expensive problem, so my code is still slow for very large numbers. That said, testing it on the above range (2-99999, inclusive), took **3.47 seconds** on my machine, compared to your code which took **37.2 minutes**.

Comment: Just noting that this is still a highly suboptimal approach. Judging from the content of the question, giving OP a complete solution in code immediately is not the best way to benefit him (aka homework questions).

Comment: @maxplus I did not get the impression that this was a homework problem. I'm sure this is not an optimal solution and I'm curious to see something more optimized.

Comment: @jared I've added an answer with optimal algorithm, as well as a non-optimal GPU version to compare.